# 1 year old SSD 64g Crucial M4 Fails to boot, freezing

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

The other day I came home from work and my computer is sitting on a fail to boot screen. I turned off the computer and checked the connections, and it turns on great. Nothing new, seen this before. About an hour later, it froze and failed to boot again, only this time it wont reboot.

The next day, I turned on the computer, and it booted just fine. An hour or so later, it froze and wont boot again.

It wont auto reboot with the reset button, you have to turn it completely off and reboot it after a few minutes.

With that being said, the SSD only has Windows on it. I have 2 other drives with my junk on it.

```
Specs:

AMD Phenom 710 x4 @ 3.2 
2x 4830 CF 
4 Gigs of 1066 Ram 
2x 640 gig Raid 0
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad controller, not much you can about that, besides retrieve what data you can off it.  Time to replace it.

Comment: It seems like the computer freezes when you come from work. Try to stay home all day, and see it still freezes.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the firmware, you need to update the firmware due to a bug. Happened to me and it only happens after ten thousand hours (or more i'm not sure what the number is any more) so you get hit with the bug after months or even a year of use. http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx

Comment: forgot to mention, if it won't boot you have to unplug it from power or open your computer and disconnect it from power so it will reset and you get the hour you need to download the firmware and make the boot disk to flash it